# How can fill the form and return back to modify the records in php

Tags: javascript, php

[image: [enter image description here]]

I want to fill the form and able to return back to modify the records. But when I return back I want the form to have the previous values. when I put " />

I got error. 
please help

Thank you!

My code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $from = 'hello@gmail.com';
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $text = $_POST['elvismail'];
    $output_form = false;
    if(empty($subject) && empty($text)) {
        echo 'You forgot the email subject and body text.<br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }
   if (empty($subject) && (!empty($text))) {
        echo 'You forgot the email subject.<br />';
        $output_form = true;
    }

    if ((!empty($subject)) && empty($text)) {
        echo 'You forgot the email body text.<br />';
        $output_form = true;

        }

   if ((!empty($subject)) && (!empty($text))) { 

       if(isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
        echo "cancel";
      }
      else if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

       echo "submit";
      }

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <table>
        <tr> 
            <td>Subject of email</td>
            <td> <?php echo $subject; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Body of email</td>
           <td><?php echo $text ?> </td>
        </tr>

        </table>
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
  }
}
else {
    $output_form=true;
}

if ($output_form) {
?>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<label for="subject">Subject of email:</label><br />
<input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" size="30" /><br />
<label for="elvismail">Body of email:</label><br />
<textarea id="elvismail" name="elvismail" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: You have required to use "javascript" to do this job

Comment: `<input id="subject" name="subject"  value="<?php $subject ?>" type="text" size="30" /><br />` does this work? you'll probably need to validate that $subject isset

Comment: I would validate this using javascript and if it passes the validation, hide the inputs and display the other view with the "submit"/"cancel" buttons, I would then use ajax to submit this data. Using ajax will save redirecting the client and save a new page being forced to load. I would do one final validation "server-side" before having the script send/save or whatever your intentions are.

Comment: by returning back do you mean , go to the previous page ? if that is the case , your page will reload and you will loose your data in the variable , but you can  use cookies .

Comment: @NewToJS  how can I return back to the previous form if I want to modify the input data ?

Comment: @ Nicolas, I tried that. But I got error

Comment: @Favian, yes I mean to return to the previous form. But how can I use cookies to get the values ?

Comment: @user7428112 simply use the cancel button to show the form again and hide the final view.

Comment: Try what @NewToJS is saying , it's a better approach . But is not easy if you are a beginner  .

Comment: This is very rough but at least it should give you an idea of how to take on my approach. A quick clean up on the source code and a quick ajax tutorial shouldn't take too long but this will save reloading/redirecting the client. https://jsfiddle.net/wy3nn7be/

Comment: @ NewToJS, Thank you very much!!! That works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario its much better to use client side resources rather than storing it again on `php`. Because it is just a temporary value and using **Local Storage** would benefit you alot.

**Javascript** or **JQuery** would be the best approach to accomplish this.

> Step 1 : **Store the value on `LocalStorage` after on blur of every input on the form.**
>
> Step 2 : **When user gets back to page. Simply assign the last data you saved on the `localStorage`**

*Because if you refresh the page you will lose the data variables in your `php` and will require to fetch it again on the `database` thus resulting on the same data values.*

I suggest you read about the [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and read about controlling inputs with JQuery.

```
x = $("#form").serialize();
localStorage.setItem("temp_form_data" , x);

// To retrieve it simply convert it to JSON and assign it to each inputs.

var temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("temp_form_data"));

$("your-input-target").value(temp.id);
$("other-input-target").value(temp.description);

//and so on
```

This is just what would the implementation look like for setting and getting input data.